# counting the number of images using php

Tags: php

I want to images as a one result.But,when I count it, it didn't get total result.It is showing "count image is->1,count image is->,etc" like this.I want to as a result count image is->2 because I want to check it using if loop."$my_img_url" is total images.
**Here is my code**

```
$snd_count+=count($my_img_url);
echo "count image is->" .$snd_count.'<br>'; 
    if($snd_count >3){....}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your $my_img_url is an array , then count function will give the total number of indexes inside it. You do not need to  use the post increment counter.

$snd_count =count($my_img_url); should do the work itself.

I would suggest you to print what is there in $my_img_url.